# Textbox text from background worker?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I've been trying to figure out how to get my textbox's text or other property from within a background worker. Does anybody know how to do this? I cannot pass it as a param because it needs to be real-time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why doesn't your current code work? Do you get exceptions? If yes, what kind?

Comment: What do you mean by "from within a background"?

Comment: @Adrian apologies, I meant 'from within a background worker'. @svick  in my current code I pass the text but by the time it gets to the part of the code were it uses the text, the text is old. So I need to get the text at the exact moment it is used from within the background worker. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the-t/142069#142069

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to just invoke the property (pseudo-code):

```
private void bgw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  // looping through stuff
  {
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Text = textBox1.Text; }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. I was not aware it was that simple.

Comment: I'm suppressed you didn't mention the exception *Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.* in your question..

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) method and event of the Background worker. That will switch to the correct thread for you.

Answer (score 2):

Or if needed in WPF:

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string text = null;
    myTextBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
    {
        text = myTextBox.Text;
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use invoke method.

here's my example.

```
delegate void myDelegate(string name);
//...
private void writeToTextbox(string fCounter)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        myDelegate textWriter = new myDelegate(displayFNums);
        this.Invoke(textWriter, new object[] { fCounter });
    }
    else
    {
        textbox1.Text = "Processing file: " + fileCounter + "of" + 100;
    }
}
//...

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //...
    writeToTextbox(fileCounter.ToString());
}
```

in dowork i manipulate some textfile and i inform the user about how many files i have processed so far.

Comment: replace "displayFNums" with your actual method name "writeToTextbox"